# Order by COUNT after a joining a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code below that currently works but after adding `COUNT` after `ORDER BY` it gave me the error

> invalid column name 'Answers'

```
SELECT  Test.SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND, 
        Test.SEARCH_TEST, 
        Test.KEYWORD as Search_Words, 
        Test2.Answers_for_exam AS Answers
FROM    Test 
INNER JOIN  Test2 ON Test.TEST_NUMBER = Test2.TEST_NUMBER
WHERE SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND = 1
ORDER BY COUNT(Answers) DESC
```

I tried to `COUNT(Test2.Answers_for_exam) AS Answers` in the 1st line but also giving the same error message.
Can I also not show the column the SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND. I only added it there for me to see the results but it's not needed to be seen.

Under the column Answers there duplicate strings. I want to order them by most count of strings. For example: car, car, paper,rock,paper, paper. I want paper to return first, followed by car then rock as paper has 3 counts, car has 2 counts and rock only has 1 count (assuming there are only 3 unique strings). If i do `ORDER BY Answers DESC` they will go by alphabetical order.

Comment: Well you don't have `GROUP BY` so none of it really makes sense.  Is this MySQL? It's kind of crazy around aggregation.  Otherwise just `GROUP BY` all the columns you want (but not Answers obviously). When you've fixed that, just change 'Answers' to `Test2.Answers_for_exam`

Comment: The dilemma is I have nothing to `GROUP BY`. Is there a workaround for getting top 10 'Answers' from that column? I am using MS SQL Server management Studio.

Comment: Can you show the data present in your table & what result you expecting?

Comment: How do you define `top 10 answers` ?, please exlain. And why don't you use just `ORDER BY Answers DESC` ?

Comment: Why don't you tried selecting TOP 10 if you just looking for Top 10 Here you can use it order by Answers_for_exam  DESC

Comment: Under the column Answers there duplicate strings. I want to order them by most count of strings. For example: car, car, paper,rock,paper, paper. I want paper to return first, followed by car then rock as paper has 3 counts, car has 2 counts and rock only has 1 count (assuming there are only 3 unique strings). If i do `ORDER BY Answers DESC` they will go by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions in the `order by`.  So, I think you want:

```
SELECT Test.SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND, 
       Test.SEARCH_TEST, 
       Test.KEYWORD as Search_Words, 
       Test2.Answers_for_exam AS Answers
FROM Test INNER JOIN
     Test2
     ON Test.TEST_NUMBER = Test2.TEST_NUMBER
WHERE SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND = 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Test2.Answers_for_exam) DESC;
```

This should be the simplest method to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thanks! How would i get the Top10 Count stings results?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . That is a different question.  It should be asked as a new question, with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

use `COUNT(*) OVER()` window function to perform the count you want and then order by it

```
SELECT  Test.SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND, 
        Test.SEARCH_TEST, 
        Test.KEYWORD as Search_Words, 
        Test2.Answers_for_exam AS Answers,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Test2.Answers_for_exam) AS AnswerCount
FROM    Test 
INNER JOIN  Test2 ON Test.TEST_NUMBER = Test2.TEST_NUMBER
WHERE SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND = 1
ORDER BY AnswerCount DESC
```

Comment: I added `LIMIT 10` to return the top10 strings by count but error 
__incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'__ came up. Can you please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of count of answers in a separate column (here `cnt`) and then order over it like below

```
SELECT 
    SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND,
    SEARCH_TEST,
    Search_Words,
    Answers
FROM
(
SELECT  Test.SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND, 
        Test.SEARCH_TEST, 
        Test.KEYWORD as Search_Words, 
        Test2.Answers_for_exam AS Answers,
        COUNT(Test2.Answers_for_exam) over ( order by (select 1)) as cnt
FROM    Test 
INNER JOIN  Test2 ON Test.TEST_NUMBER = Test2.TEST_NUMBER
WHERE SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND = 1
)T 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

You can also use group by like below

```
SELECT  Test.SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND, 
        Test.SEARCH_TEST, 
        Test.KEYWORD as Search_Words, 
        Test2.Answers_for_exam AS Answers
FROM    Test 
INNER JOIN  Test2 ON Test.TEST_NUMBER = Test2.TEST_NUMBER
WHERE SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND = 1
GROUP BY 
        Test.SOLUTION_NOT_FOUND, 
        Test.SEARCH_TEST, 
        Test.KEYWORD as Search_Words, 
        Test2.Answers_for_exam
ORDER BY COUNT(Test2.Answers_for_exam) DESC
```